# How to move files in a bff?

Tags: aix

I am building a bff using mkinstallp.

My template file is :

```
Package Name: svr_exForum
Package VRMF: 7.2
Update: N
Fileset
        Fileset Name: svr_exForum.rte
        Fileset VRMF: 7.2
        USRLIBLPPFiles
                Pre-installation Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_pre_i
                Post-installation Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_post_i
                Pre_rm Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_prerm_i
                Unpre-installation Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_unpre_i
                Unpost-installation Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_unpost_i
                Pre-deinstall Script: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/F_predes_i
        EOUSRLIBLPPFiles
        USRFiles
                /exForum7/
                /exForum7/full/
                /exForum7/full/exForum7
                /exForum7/exForum7up
        EOUSRFiles
        Fileset Description: Package d'installation du produit exForum pour aix versions 6.1-7.1
        Bosboot required: N
        License agreement acceptance required: N
        Include license files in this package: N
        Copyright file path: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/svr_exForum.copyright
        Requisites:
        ROOT Part: N
        ROOTLIBLPPFiles
        EOROOTLIBLPPFiles
        ROOTFiles
        EOROOTFiles
        Relocatable: N
        OVERRIDE_INVENTORY: /lppdir/lpp/exForum/svr_exForum.override
EOFileset
```

I have a compressed source file and once decompress I have to move some files in a different location.
In my Post-installation Script I am then moving some of the USRFiles is a different location.

If I do that when installing the bff I get the following error message :

```
sysck: 3001-022 The file ...   was not found.
```

Is there a way to skeep the test done during the installation of the bff that verify if all the USRFiles are present?
If I have done the same operations in rpm packages and I would use the missingok in the %files section.